# how to solve redundant data in listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, qr-code

i have a listbox which will show the qr code decoded text. once the qr code is decoded, the text from qr code would be listed out in listbox. the program decode it very fast which result a multiple text entry with the same data to the listbox. i would like to program a the listbox to show only 1 decoded text and would not show the same text which is resultant of multiple time decoding of the same qr code.

[image]

below is my listbox source code. i assume additional programming need to be done there. would be happy to receive any suggestion or tutorial on the matter

```
    /// <summary>
    /// To show the result of decoding. the result is feed to Barcode Format, QR          Content and Scanned item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="result"></param>
    private void ShowResult(Result result)
    {
        currentResult = result;
        txtBarcodeFormat.Text = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
        txtContent.Text = result.Text;
        fill_listbox();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Item scanned will be listed in listbox
    /// </summary>
    void fill_listbox()
    {
        string item = txtContent.Text;
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);

        textBox1.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();


    }
```

thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could check if the list box already contains the item:

```
void fill_listbox()
{
    string item = txtContent.Text;
    if(!listBox.Items.Contains(item))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
    textBox1.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();


}
```

Comment: sir, dont really understand. no need to write argument?

Answer (score 0):

If I am to presume that `listBox1` is a `List` than you can change this to a `Set` and prevent duplicates from being added.  If it is a different object, you would have to invoke a `Contains` method or iterate over the object internals:

```
bool shouldAdd = true;
for(Foo foo : listBox1)  
{  
     if(foo == toAdd)  
     {   
        shouldAdd = false;
        break;

     }  
}  
if(shouldAdd)  
{  
    listBox1.Add(toAdd);
}
```

It is imperative that you override equals and hashcode.

Comment: Hi sir, alright, i am giving it a shot now. thanks for showing the way.